# New HashMap is pointing to old HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to implement a graph algorithm using a HashMap with integer keys, and an ArrayList for the values.

The key is the vertex, and the ArrayList is all of the vertices that are connected to the key vertex.

I'm using a blacklist to keep track of where I've been. If the item is in the blacklist, I HAVE NOT visited that vertex yet. The problem with this code is that I have to be able to call a search multiple times while the program is running. What I'm doing is pointing blacklist to the graph with the vertices. Then, as I visit a vertex, I delete the value in the blackList. The problem being, the blackList is pointing to the value in the original graph. So when I run the search again, the original graph is missing all the vertexes I visited my previous search.

The TL:DR question is this: how do I created a new identical HashMap without pointing.

I understand that I could loop through the HashMap and copy over each entry, but if I'm doing a lot of searches(large searches at that!), it gets slow. I'm not above doing it that way if that is the only way to do it.

```
 //The class variables used for this search
 HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> mapBlacklist;
 Queue<Integer> line = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
 int searchFor;
 boolean areTheyConnected;

 //The constructor I'm using
 GraphSearch(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph, int match){
    mapBlacklist = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>(graph);
    searchFor = match;
 }
 //The search method.
 void numberOne(int start, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph){
    if(graph.get(start).contains(this.searchFor)){
        this.areTheyConnected = true;
    }
    else{
        while(!this.mapBlacklist.get(start).isEmpty()){
            this.line.add(this.mapBlacklist.get(start).get(0) ;
            this.mapBlacklist.get(start).remove(0);
        }
    }

    if(!this.line.isEmpty() && !this.areTheyConnected){
            numberOne(this.line.remove(), graph);
    }
}
```

In the main method:

```
/* What it looks like in the command line to see if vertices 2 5 are connected:
       1 2 5

   To close the program:
       0
*/
boolean keepGoing = true;
    while(keepGoing){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number0 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
        if(number0 == 0){
            keepGoing = false;
            sc.close();
        }
        else if(number0 == 1){
            int number1 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
            int number2 = Integer.parseInt(sc.next());
           // GraphSearch gsearch = new GraphSearch(graph, number2);
            GraphSearch gsearch = new GraphSearch(mapGraph, number2);
            gsearch.numberOne(number1, mapGraph);
            System.out.println(gsearch.areTheyConnected);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need this mapBlacklist in the first place?

I can see from your algorithm that you can just use your queue to iterate (recursively) over all non-visited items.

In the loop:

```
while(!this.mapBlacklist.get(start).isEmpty()){
        this.line.add(this.mapBlacklist.get(start).get(0) ;
        this.mapBlacklist.get(start).remove(0);
    }
```

just don't use black list and don't remove anything from graph. You can only iterate over the list in current vertex and add all the items in it to the queue.

Does it make sence?

Comment: Because the the graph can be multi-directional. I.E. vertex 1 points to 2, but vertex 2 points back to one. Then vertex one would go back to vertex 2.

Comment: Then may be instead of removing visited nodes from black list, you can add them to separated visitedList and check whis list before adding next node to a queue?

And initially visitedList is empty so you don't have this mess with changing the graph during iterating over it.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way you're using `mapBlackList` confusing, and I think that confusion is contributing to your problem.

You don't need to know the structure of the map to prevent revisits, just what you've visited during this search.  So instead of making a shallow copy of the whole graph in the constructor, why not simply keep a `Set<Integer>` of the vertices you've visited so far?  Your search method than becomes something like:

```
void numberOne(int start, HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> graph){
  visited.add(start);

  if(graph.get(start).contains(this.searchFor)){
    this.areTheyConnected = true;
    return;
  }
  else{
    for (Integer destination : graph.get(start)) {          
      if (!areTheyConnected && !visited.contains(destination)) {
        numberOne(destination, graph);          
      }
    }
  }
}
```